# Something Wrong On My python :float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, typeerror

I am right now a Python newcomer, and I study this by finishing courses on http://www.codecademy.com. This website offers an online judge system just like an ACM to exam if my code works fine. And it works great on my others code except this one.

I tried to copy this code to my local pc with Python 2.6 installed and it works.

By the way, can you suggest some Python grammar books to a beginner like me, I just want to know a little inner detail about this language...

Because I cannot post a picture here I just paste the code below:

on my mac:
:

```
    [~ tk$]cat test8.py 
def median(li):

    if len(li) >= 2:
        li_test = sorted(li)
        if len(li_test)%2 == 0:
            cd1 = len(li_test)/2-1
            cd2 = cd1 
            re = (li_test[cd1] + li_test[cd2])/2.0
        else:
            cd = (len(li_test)+1)/2-1
            re = li_test[cd]
    else:
        re = li
    return re
print median([1,2,3])

[~ tk$]python test8.py 

2

[~ tk$]
```

on the websites: the title is : Practice makes perfect 15/15:

```
def median(li):

    if len(li) >= 2:
        li_test = sorted(li)
        if len(li_test)%2 == 0:
            cd1 = len(li_test)/2-1
            cd2 = cd1 
            re = (li_test[cd1] + li_test[cd2])/2.0
        else:
            cd = (len(li_test)+1)/2-1
            re = li_test[cd]
    else:
        re = li
    return re


Oops, try again. Your function crashed on [1] as input because your function throws a "float() argument must be a string or a number" error.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else:
    re = li
```

The error is occurring because if the length of `li` is 1 or 0, then you are returning the `list` `li`.

```
>>> median([1])
[1]
>>> median([0])
[0]
```

Maybe you want

```
if len(li) >= 1:
  ...
else:
    raise IndexError("No items in this list")
```

Another bug in your code is if there are even number of elements in the list, you should take the average of the two middle elements. But in your code,

```
    if len(li_test)%2 == 0:
        cd1 = len(li_test)/2-1
        cd2 = cd1 
        re = (li_test[cd1] + li_test[cd2])/2.0
```

You take one of the two middle elements, and add the same number twice and divide by two. It should be

```
    if len(li_test) % 2 == 0:
        cd1 = len(li_test) / 2
        cd2 = cd1 - 1
        re = (li_test[cd1] + li_test[cd2])/2.0
```

Comment: No, I don't think I can do that. It is a online judge system, So I can only make my codes to satisfy its criterion. In the case thatthe length of [1] is 1, clearly the median number is 1 so I just returned the number. I can't see the mistake.

Comment: You are returning the `list` `[1]` not the `int` `1`

Comment: TK, to illustrate Jay's second point -- what is the median of `[1,3]`?

Comment: Sorry, I am just being busy with my Classes.. I know where my fault is already.[0] and 0 is not the same thing. Sorry I used to be a Matlab user and those two are pretty confusing. It looks I need some more practices. Thanks for your guys help.